# Unable to control Windows service created with sc

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I created a Windows service for my application using a batch file containing the instruction:

```
sc create <name> binPath= "C:\my\path\" DisplayName= "MyName"
```

The service is created successfully and the application runs without issues. The Windows Service Manager shows the service in the list, however it does not have the "started" status, even though it is running. Clicking on "start service" fails with "*Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion*".

When attempting to control the service using the `net` command, such as

```
net stop <name>
```

or

```
net start <name>
```

these commands fail with similar error messages.

This happens consistently on all Windows I tested on (up to Windows 7). Restarting the machine does not change anything.

Any reason why a successfully created and running service **cannot** be started or stopped (or even have its status recognized)?

Comment: Can you include the code with which your program receives SCM notifications? (Ie. the function you passed to `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` if Win32; or the handlers for the `OnStart` etc. if .NET, in your `ServiceBase` subclass.)

Comment: My program does no such thing... It is a cross-platform java application encapsulated within a .exe. Why should my program implement any such handler methods anyway? Linux machines can stop and start any service at any time without communicating with the service at all.

Comment: The *nix daemon process model is completely different to Windows Services. To be a Window's Service your application needs to communicate with the Windows SCM. There might be a wrapper process you can use that will proxy things for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had no idea there was this additional layer of communication on Windows. I will look into it. In the meantime post the above as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I've added an answer

Comment: One candidate for a helper program: https://nssm.cc/

Comment: Hi Harry. Yes I am trying that out at the moment, it looks pretty good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Including information from comments to the question.)

Linux daemon processes are controlled through signals.

Windows Services have a completely model. The process needs to connect to the Service Control Manager (SCM: the `services.exe` process) on start up to provide a callback. This callback is the main entry to the service, and also how the SCM signals important events (eg. that the service should stop).

This is covered on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and .NET has specific support (by subclassing [`ServiceBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

It maybe possible to find a helper program that provides the SCM integration and launches you program, but likely it will just terminate your processes (*nix style signals do not exist on Windows) on the SCM sending a stop.